# How to merge 2 numpy arrays and concatenate their values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

Is there a way to obtain the same result from this Python-arrays merge:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

b = [4,3,2,1]

c = [ int(''.join (map (str, xs))) for xs in zip (a,b) ]

c
Out[4]: [14, 23, 32, 41]
```

But operating directly on **Numpy**-arrays:

```
a
Out[9]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

b
Out[10]: array([4, 3, 2, 1])

c = Your Answer

c
# desired output: array([14, 23, 32, 41])
```

My first (and obvious) solution was:

```
c = np.array([int(''.join (map(str, xs))) for xs in zip(a.tolist(),b.tolist())])

c
Out[12]: array([14, 23, 32, 41])
```

But I would like to know if it's possible to do that directly with the numpy-arrays, without converting them to python-arrays.

Note: I use 1,2,3,4 values for simplification, I would like to have a solution that work with +double digits on both arrays of size > 10**4.

---

## Updated with timings for different solutions:

```
a = np.arange(1000000)

b = np.arange(1,1000001)

#: Mi first Solution
%%timeit
c = np.array([int(''.join (map(str, xs))) for xs in zip(a.tolist(),b.tolist())])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.99 s per loop

#: Donkey's Solution (thought to smaller arrays)
%%timeit
c = np.char.add(a.astype(str),b.astype(str)).astype(int)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.8 s per loop

#: My second Solution
%%timeit
c = merge(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 128 ms per loop

#: Divakar's Solution
%%timeit
c = a*(10**(np.log10(b).astype(int)+1)) + b
10 loops, best of 3: 117 ms per loop
```

## Verify results:

```
c1 = np.array([int(''.join (map(str, xs))) for xs in zip(a.tolist(),b.tolist())])

c2 = np.char.add(a.astype(str),b.astype(str)).astype(int)

c3 = merge(a,b)

np.alltrue(np.logical_and(c1==c2,c2==c3))
Out[51]: True


c4 = a*(10**(np.log10(b).astype(int)+1)) + b

np.alltrue(np.logical_and(c1==c2,c2==c4))
Out[58]: True
```

Comment: check out the numpy.char module

Comment: Try `c = 10*a + b`

Comment: I've checked the module and found a quickly answer. Thanks Eelco.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Andrey, but that operation doesn't return the answer that I want when the 2 arrays contain double digits. Probably my fault the fact of not indicate that I wanted an answer apliccable to double digits also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using NumPy mathematical functions -

```
a*(10**(np.log10(b).astype(int)+1)) + b
```

Sample run -

```
In [32]: a
Out[32]: array([ 16,   2, 399,   4])

In [33]: b
Out[33]: array([  4,  38,   2, 190])

In [34]: a*(10**(np.log10(b).astype(int)+1)) + b
Out[34]: array([ 164,  238, 3992, 4190])
```

Comment: Thanks divakar. I had founded about 10 minutes ago a similar approach. Just  like yours but with support to 0s and numbers formed by only 9s.

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia Could you add this to your timings test in the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `dtype` parameter to have your numpy arrays be `string` arrays, on which you can simply use the free function `add` in `numpy.char` to concatenate them string-wise, like so

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4], dtype=numpy.str)
b = numpy.array([4,3,2,1], dtype=numpy.str)

c = numpy.char.add(a, b).astype(int)
```

**Outputs**:

```
[14 23 32 41]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was just writing the same solution at the same time ^^

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia Cheers, glad I could help.

Comment: I think I found a quite faster solution ^^

Answer (score 1):

I write a function with a solution that I found after thinking a while:

```
def merge(a,b):
#: I don't find a better way to create this array
nines = np.array([9,99,999,9999,99999,999999,9999999, 99999999])

#: get number of digits
exp = np.log10(a)+1

#: fix the zeros
exp[exp == -np.inf] = 1

#: fix the nines
exp[np.in1d(a,nines)] += 1

c = a * 10**exp.astype(int) + b
return c
```

It might appear to be too much overthinking but it's **a lot** (x10) faster than the other solutions:

```
%%timeit
c = merge(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 128 ms per loop
```

Comment: I don't think it is any faster, actually. Rather twice as slow. I'd double check your use of `timeit`.

Comment: Ah, no now I see you've tested for 10 million elements. For a smaller case (like your example in your question) the solution I posted is twice as fast.

Comment: Sorry about the misleading example, I was trying to simplificate the situation but I should especify wich what kind of arrays I was working at (big and +double digits). I updated the answer